# UIView - similar method to ViewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm creating an app that uses only `Storyboard` (no separate xib-s). 
Here is a screenshot of how my storyboard looks:

[image]

Each of the three view controllers (one with "infinite" and "Levels" labels, one with two switches, and one with some label), is assigned correctly to .h and .m files.

And here's my issue - how to call something like `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear`, or `ViewDidAppear`?
I tried to call 
`-(void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview`, but it doesn't work as `viewDidLoad`.

How to solve it?

---

And, in OptionsController.m, I can't call any of viewDid... or viewWill... functions

---

In interface, I had heritance from UIView. I changed it to UIViewController, and now I have all those methods, but now when I click on a button that should present "OptionsController", I get an error :[OptionsController _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ab94e0'" – Artur Bartczak 1 hour ago delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each viewcontroller in your storyboard you have to add a .h and .m file to your project. the name of the file is the class name you entered in the inspector in your storyboard for the viewcontroller. so if you have a MainViewController of type UITableViewController you have to add the file via "new file" to your project. then in this files you call viewDidLoad and the other.

for your storyboard: select the first entry "ViewController". in the inspector(right panel), under custom class enter a unique class name, OptionsViewController for example. then select the project panel(left panel), select the left icon for file browsing. right click and select "new file". in the dialog select ios->cocoa touch->objective c class then next. now enter exactly the same name as in storyboard under custom class. for subclass select the parent class, if you drag a UIViewController in your storyboard, you have to enter here the same.
next select the directory to save and click create.

now if you click on the new created .m file you see the method viewDidLoad which you now can modify.

Comment: I only have DrawRect function, and no viewDidLoad is there :(

Comment: then you did something wrong. open your OptionsViewController.h and see if you find the following code: @interface OptionsViewController : UIViewController ...

Comment: you should read a good basic tutorial, try this one, it will answer a lot of your problems -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: In interface, I had heritance from UIView. I changed it to UIViewController, and now I have all those methods, but now when I click on a button that should present "OptionsController", I get an error :[OptionsController _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ab94e0'"

Comment: that would be another questions. if this solves your first problem accept this as answer :-) ... and please read the tutorial...

Comment: as i wrote: this is another question. not a comment. the question from the title is solved ;-)